# add values to array by iterate one at a time

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to get this function working by adding one point at at time, till there are no more. 
What I am trying to do is, getting it to increment `"Torsk"` value by one, then go to the next, increment by one, and then so on an on, till all the points set in `$prize` have been distributed.

```
$prize = [
    "Torsk" => 0,
    "Rødspætte" => 0,
    "Mørksej" => 0,
    "Skrubbe" => 0,
    "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 0,
    "Ising" => 0,
    "Lange" => 0,
    "Makrel" => 0,
    "Hornfisk" => 0,
    "Pig-/Slet-hvar" => 0,
    "Havkat" => 0,
    "Laks/Havørred" => 0,
];

$points = 21;

for ($i = 0; $i < $points; ++$i) {

    foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {

      $prize[$key]++;

      if (array_sum($prize) == $points) continue;

    }
}

echo array_sum($prize);
echo "<br />";
print_r($prize);
```

When it is finished I expected the array to be like this:

```
$prize = [
    "Torsk" => 2,
    "Rødspætte" => 2,
    "Mørksej" => 2,
    "Skrubbe" => 2,
    "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 2,
    "Ising" => 2,
    "Lange" => 2,
    "Makrel" => 2,
    "Hornfisk" => 2,
    "Pig-/Slet-hvar" => 1,
    "Havkat" => 1,
    "Laks/Havørred" => 1,
];
```

But it is not, instead it has just added 21 to all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [break 2;](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) to break from outer loop when your condition is reached, like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($prize); ++$i) {

    foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {

      $prize[$key]++;

      if (array_sum($prize) == $points) {
          break 2;
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's really nice solution!

Comment: `count($prize)` why you used this, what if `count($prize) = 10` and `$points = 21`, the `array_sum($prize) == $points` will never be true, and then the `for` loop will end without getting what he want(disturbing the array until the sum of its values equal to `$points`).

Comment: Would it be possible to change the array like this:
`$prize = [
    array('art' => 'Torsk', 'praemier' => 0),
    array('art' => 'Rødspætte', 'praemier' => 0),
    array('art' => 'Mørksej', 'praemier' => 0),
    ];`

and then get it to write the value to 'praemier' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
$prize = [
        "Torsk" => 0,
        "Rødspætte" => 0,
        "Mørksej" => 0,
        "Skrubbe" => 0,
        "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 0,
        "Ising" => 0,
        "Lange" => 0,
        "Makrel" => 0,
        "Hornfisk" => 0,
        "Pig-/Slet-hvar" => 0,
        "Havkat" => 0,
        "Laks/Havørred" => 0,
];

$points = 21;

foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {

    $prize[$key]++;

    if (array_sum($prize) == $points) break;

}

if(array_sum($prize) < $points){
    foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {

        $prize[$key]++;

        if (array_sum($prize) == $points) break;

    }    
}   

echo array_sum($prize);
echo "<br />";
print_r($prize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `break 2;` instead of `continue` to break the two nested enclosing structures.

The following is an improved way to do the same task.

```
<?php


/**
 * Disturbe values until the sum is equal to $points
 * @param $prize array
 * @param $points integer
 * @return array|false
 */
function distribute_prize( $prize = array(), $points = 21 ){

    $sum = array_sum( $prize );
    if( $sum == $points ) return $points;
    elseif( $sum > $points || $points < 0 ) return false;

    while( true ){
        foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {
            $prize[$key]++;
            if( array_sum( $prize ) == $points ) break 2;

        }
    }

    return $prize;
}

// TEST
$prize = [
    "Torsk" => 0,
    "Rødspætte" => 0,
    "Mørksej" => 0,
    "Skrubbe" => 0,
    "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 0,
    "Ising" => 0,
    "Lange" => 0,
    "Makrel" => 0,
    "Hornfisk" => 0,
    "Pig-/Slet-hvar" => 0,
    "Havkat" => 0,
    "Laks/Havørred" => 0,
];

$points = 21;
print_r( distribute_prize( $prize, $points ) );
```